# What is the size of an empty 4G network packet (with TCP/IP)?

Tags: mobile, traffic, 4g

Fellow users,

What is the size of an empty 4G packet (LTE Protocol Stack) with TCP/IP?
I'm not looking for the MTU, but the minimum number of bytes necessary to build a LTE Protocol packet with TCP/IP.
I was able to find an equivallent answer for Ethernet and IEEE 802.11, but not for 4G (see [1] and [2]).

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846077/size-of-empty-udp-and-tcp-pack

[2] https://superuser.com/questions/243008/whats-the-minimum-size-of-a-tcp-packet

Comment: "4G" is an marketing term for several technologies. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: 4G simply stands for 4th Generation - it doesn't really mean anything specific, so you'll have to clarify your question.

Comment: @Zac67 I mean the LTE Stack